# When were names ending in -в romanized with -ff?

Tags: транслитерация, выбор-имени, английский

Russian surnames ending in -в used to be transliterated for English speakers with *ff*, e.g. "Petroff" and "Prokofieff". Today *v* seems more accepted. None of the various modern and historical Romanization systems listed in Wikipedia appear suggest *ff*.

Was this an exception based on the sound's position at word end? I gather there is a phonological case for using the letter *f*, but apparently doing so is out of style in the age of formal standards.

Which sort of romanization resulted in the *ff* and when was it in use?

Comment: Asking why exactly in particular language N Russian surnames are romanized this particular way is actually not about Russian language.

Comment: Aaron, actually you are asking about why in English Russian last names are usually spelled with -ff - but it's actually not a question about Russian at all.

Comment: I think it was popular among those who targeted German language rather than English. The -ff ending would make them look more Germanesque. There is a lot of words ending with -off in German, such as "Stoff", "Hoff" etc.

Comment: Yes, I also heard that -ff ending was because of German language. Actually English as a base language for transliteration is used during last 25 years. Before that time (in USSR) the official transliteration standard was based on French language.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing